# How do i make a circle change fill when hovered over with CSS in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I have a circle that is inside an hBox. Now i want that circle to change its fill to another color when the mouse cursor hovers over it. Is that possible to do in JavaFX with CSS, if not what is the best way to do it programmatically?
i tried:

```
#circleID: hover {
    -fx-background-color: #fff;
    -fx-fill: #fff;
    -fx-cell-hover-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the circle is a shape so try with fill method :

```
#circleID{

-fx-fill:red;


}

#circleID:hover{

-fx-fill:blue;

}
```

and in your java code add this :

```
circle.setId("circleID");
```

Comment: I tried that, as you can see in the question description. It didn't work though.

Comment: I gave the circle an ID in Scene Builder, and used CSS to fill it and it worked, but the hover effect doesn't

Comment: It worked perfectly for me, try to reload your Scene Builder and save change in fxml file.

Comment: Thank you it works not. I didn't notice i already applied a fill effect through scene builder before i did it in css. I removed them from scene builder and now the hover works fine.